# how to call a function when auto_ptr is a parameter of it!

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class test
{
     private:
         int x , y;
     public:
         test(int a , int b):x(a),y(b){}
         void fun()
         {
            std::cout<< x<<" "<<y<<" "<<std::endl;
         }
};

void show(std::auto_ptr<test> t1)
{
    t1->fun();
}

int main()
{

    show(new test(3,4));

}
```

I am getting a compilation error , please tell me what's wrong in this code?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James explained how to resolve the problem.

But the reason auto_ptr was designed so that you can not do this:

```
show(new test(3,4));
```

Is because this is a bad idea.
Even this (if it were allowed):

```
show(std::auto_ptr<test>(new test(3,4)));
```

Would be a bad idea.
So you ask why.

Well in the normal situation not a big deal.
Bu what happens when you have a function that takes more than one parameter.

```
show2(std::auto_ptr<test>(new test(3,4)), SomeObject());
```

Now the standard gurantees that all parameters will be fully evaluated before the call (even the construction of the auto_ptr). But it does not guarantee the evaluation order nor that the evaluation will not be interleaved.

Thus it is possible for this evaluation:

```
  // Phsedu code for parameter evaluation
  test*                      tmp1 = new test(3,4);
  SomeObject const&          tmp2 = SomeObject();
  std::auto_ptr<test> const& tmp3(tmp1);
call(tmp3, tmp1)
```

This order is bad. Because if the constructor of SomeObject throws an exception you will leak tmp1 as it has not yet been assigned to the std::auto_ptr.

This is why we auto_ptr was designed so that you have to give it a named variable.

```
std::auto_ptr<test>  tmp3(new test(3,4));
SomeObject           tmp1;
call(tmp3, tmp1)
```

Now if SomObject constructor throws the test object will be tidied up.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you dynamically allocate an object, you should create a *named* smart pointer that immediately takes ownership of the object, then use that named smart pointer.  For example,

```
std::auto_ptr<test> ptr(new test(3, 4));
show(ptr);
```

You cannot pass `new test(3, 4)` directly to the function because `std::auto_ptr` objects must be explicitly constructed; it would be quite unexpected if a smart pointer took ownership of an object implicitly.

That said, this is rather unusual anyway because when you call `show()`, the `auto_ptr` is copied and when `auto_ptr` is "copied," the original loses ownership and the copy gains ownership (so, after `show()` is called, you will find that `ptr` no longer has ownership of the object.

Comment: +1.  In fact, you will find the object gets destructed when the function exits, as `t1` goes out of scope.  (Also, you might or might not want to give the rationale, or a link, explaining the importance of using _named_ smart pointers.  Something to do with constructors and exceptions, as I recall...)